# Cauchy Principal Value for Poles stronger than 1

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, regularization

While calculating the Cauchy Principal Value of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ we take an indented semicircle (in the upper half plane) of radius $\delta$ centered at the simple pole of $\frac{e^{iz}}{z}$ at $z=0$. Then we Laurent expand and by integrating and taking $\delta\rightarrow0$ we obtain over the small semicircle (in $\pi\rightarrow0$ clockwise sense): $$\int\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz=-i\pi\qquad\text{Residue at}\,z=0=-i\pi$$ (As done in Arfken $7^{th}$ edition,  $11.75$).

But this method fails when we have poles stronger than of order $1$, e.g., $\frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}}$. How do I approach such cases?

Comment: $\delta$ comes in denominator and then you can't take the limit $\delta\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: The integral over an even integrand that diverges like this doesn't have a principal value. Loosely speaking, ~1/x does, because it's odd, so the parts from the positive and negative real axis cancel, and we just have to assign a meaning to the point at the origin. This doesn't work for an even integrand, where just removing the point at the origin doesn't help you.

Comment: However, what you've written is confusing: first you mention $\sin(x)/x$, which is regular everywhere anyway, so you never need to worry about the principal value. Then you mention $e^{iz}/z$, but it's only the *cosine* part of this that gives you the non-trivial principal value. Then you go to $e^{iz}$, but with $z^{-2}$. Now the sine part has a principal value, because it's odd near the origin, but the cosine part has none because it's even, as I said above.

Comment: Related: [Principal value integral](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31175/2451)

Comment: For poles of even power you use Hadamard finite part, not Cauchy principal value.

Answer (score 1):

$\oint z^n dz =0$ except for $n=-1$. So expand $e^{iz}$ as a series
$$\oint \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} dz =\oint \frac{1+iz-z^2+\dots}{z^2} dz =i\oint \frac{1}{z} dz=-2\pi$$
More generally, if $f(z)$ is regular at $z=0$
$$\oint \frac{f(z)}{z^2} dz =2\pi i f'(0)$$

---

As pointed out in the comments, the question is actually about a semicircle. Let me show this is still a (partially) valid way to calculate it in that case for the function $f(z)=e^{iz}$

$$\oint \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} dz =\int_+ \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} dz + \int_- \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} dz$$
The plus and minus refer to upper and lower semicircles. We can bring the lower semicircle integration to an upper semicircle integration by changing variables from $z\rightarrow -z$
$$\oint \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} dz =\int_+ \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{z^2} dz =\int_+ \frac{2i \sin z}{z^2} dz$$
So it is true that
$$\oint \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} dz =\oint \frac{i\sin z}{z^2} dz=2\int_+ \frac{i \sin z}{z^2} dz$$
In principle though there is a part coming from $\int_+ \frac{ \cos z}{z^2} dz$ which cancels on the full closed integral (since it comes with opposite sign). This part is logarithmically divergent as the radius of semicircle integration goes to zero, so without specifying the regularization of the integral further you can't proceed.

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question. This explains what the integral would be if the contour encircles the higher-order pole. However, the OP is concerned about the case where the contour is an indented semicircle  that doesn't encircle the pole completely.

Comment: My mistake for reading too quickly, but just flip the sign since you are going clockwise and take half of the value. Clearly the upper and lower semicircles give the same contribution to the full closed loop in this case.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work :( It could be used as a *loose* explanation for the case of why the principal value at a simple pole is half the value of its residue, but it is not at all clear as to why it may be so. I believe it no longer works for higher order poles, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: Are you saying that for poles of *any* order the contribution to an integral along an indented contour will always be half the residue? Or only for simple poles? Because I would be very surprised if it worked for poles of any order.

Comment: @Philip, I think it's for any order, but it's not valid for any $f(z)$, it's due to the properties of $f(z)$ under flipping $z\rightarrow -z$. Just give me a moment to be sure, and write it up. You are right this is a little more difficult question than I initially thought.

Comment: Sure! Take all the time you need! :)

Comment: @Philip, I edited it. There is a convergent part which is half the full closed integral and a divergent part which cancels in the full closed integral.